# PHP Declare and Assign Variable (Same Name as Function Name) Before Declaring A Function

Tags: php, function, class, methods

I've seen in a small PHP project that there is a code pattern where a variable (array) with the same name as a function declared following this variable, and this variable is assigned value:

$index

function index()

$emptyAction

function emptyAction()

My questions are: 1. what is the variable doing here, and why using the same name as the name of the function?
                    2. Is there a documentation in PHP regarding this pattern?

I have done diligent research in stack overflow and elsewhere, and have not been able to find an answer.

```
<?php
namespace app\index\controller;
use think\Controller;

class Index extends Controller
{
    public $index=[
        'login'=>false
        ];

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->fetch();
    }

    public $emptyAction=[
        'login'=>false
    ];
    public function emptyAction()
    {
        $this->response();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the variable doing here, and why using the same name as the name of the function?

No, there is no relation between a class name and a variable. You can change the variable name if you want.

> Is there a documentation in PHP regarding this pattern?

No need of documentation you can just learn about PHP Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: there is a login.js in the project with the following code: var login={
    //登录状态
    login_status:false
} I still don't quite understand: if the variable is doing nothing here, why is there?

Comment: `var login` means variable login it is just a JavaScript variable.

Comment: Yes in your question code variable is playing an imp role it is an array with data `'login'=>false` inside it.

Comment: I am using PHPStorm ide, and it shows $emptyAction and function emptyAction() as Unused element, while there is no warning for $index and function index(), meaning $index is being used somehow, right? Could you please further explain what is $index doing here ?

Comment: Yes right, as you have provided only half a code as per your code `$index` is just an array holding the data and may be using further as you have not provided whole code can't tell exactly where

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way in Phpstorm to find out the usages?

Comment: @sunyaer I do not use Phpstrom IDE so can't tell you much about it.

Comment: @sunyaer if my answer helped you please can you accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214062/discussion-between-sunyaer-and-kunal-raut).